# How can I acess HttpRequest inside Html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, httprequest

Can I acess the request object inside an html file using JavaScript? My task is to get the   requested URL from the client browser, I can't use a window.href because browser will be having different url. I can only see the exact url which is requested using http watch, how can I get that particular url, In my case the webseal is acting as the proxy, it will call my html page once it gets the request from browser. If I can acess request object inside the java script, I can do request.geturi()

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that. JavaScript runs on the client side browser and you can acces only what the browser receives